# Getting row data from Ingot_JQuery_JqGrid

Tags: zend-framework, jqgrid

I'm using Ingot_JQuery_JqGrid in my Zend project. I know how to edit data with a double click, but have no idea how to simply extract data from the selected row.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, so our fix to the problem was sending the parameter through an ajax request:

```
function sendRowId(rowid,status) {


    var myData = "row=" + rowid;
    $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo $this->url( array ('module' => 'gmarim', 'controller' => 'student', 'action' => 'select'), null, false, true );?>",
          data : myData,
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(d,s,x){

          },
          async: false
        }); 
}
```